# Point along path interpolation translate function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to recreate a 'point-along-path' d3 visualization by following this code: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868.

It looks pretty simple, I just cannot understand the parameters in the nested functions within the 'translateAlong' function that is called every 10 seconds:

```
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

In the first nested anonymous function:

- d is always undefined
- i is equal to 0
- a is equal to 'translate(480,200)' (the coordinates of the starting point of the path)

In the second nested anonymous function:

- t gradually increases from 0 to 1 over the 10 seconds to that the animation runs

My question is **where are the d,i, and a parameters coming from in the first anonymous function**, and **how are they used to get t in the second anonymous function**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`translateAlong` returns a function that'll be invoked by `d3` when the transition starts and `d3` will call it passing parameters for `d`, `i` and `a` where:

1. `d` is the datum bound to element the transition is occurring on.  This is always undefined since no data is bound to that circle.
2. `i` is index of the element in its selection.  It is always 0 since it's the only element in the selection.
3. `a` is a little more mysterious as the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_attrTween) doesn't mention it.  Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v3.5.17/src/transition/attr.js#L49) it's invoked as `tween.call(this, d, i, this.getAttribute(name))`, so as you noticed `d3` is going to pass the value of the attribute being adjusted, in this case the transform.

Alas, since none of these parameters are actually used in the tween, Mr. Bostock could have just coded it:

```
return function() {
  return function(t) {
    ...
```

Continuing on then, this function then returns another function with the signature `function(t)`.  This is the function `d3` will call **at each step** in the transition passing the parameter `t` that represents the current step/time in the transition.

Comment: Great-one more thing. In your answer you say the last returned function ('function(t)') will be returned **at each step** in the transition, and the d3 'attrTween' docs state: **"The returned interpolator is then invoked for each frame of the transition"**.

I am wondering what controls the number of steps or frames in the transition. I understand that the overall time of the transition will be 10 seconds in the example code I posted, but it looks like the interpolation function is being called a different amount of times for each subsequent transition (~1300-1450 times over the 10 seconds)

Comment: No, not returned at each step rather executed at each step.  And I should have used the word "frame" instead of "step" to be consistent with the docs but I meant the same thing.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt done when I first submitted my comment above - wondering what controls how many steps or executions occur over the course of the transition.

Comment: This is browser dependent.  If supported `d3` will use `requestAnimationFrame` which according to mozilla's [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), you should get about 60 frames per second (FPS).  If `requestAnimationFrame` is not available, `d3` will use a `setTimeout` every 17 milliseconds (which is also about 60 FPS).  How long it runs and hence how many frames is dependent on the duration of the transition.  Source code is [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v3.5.17/src/event/timer.js#L8).

Answer (score 2):

The first function is returned as a parameter to `attrTween` which, according to the [`transition.attrTween` documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_attrTween), expects a function that it can call with those `d`, `i`, and `a` parameters, to get a function that will be passed the time `t`. Without understanding of the documented interface these probably seem like arbitrary or magical parameters.